# Warning: ftp_login(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in

Tags: php, ftp, php-5.4

I am pretty new to php, trying to connect to server via ftp to upload images, but i am only allowed to use fsockopen thru port 80(http) and 443(https), but i am getting this error `Warning: ftp_login(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in`
Can anyone help? THanks!
The error is called on this line 
   $login = ftp_login($connect, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

```
  <?php

$ftp_user_name='name';
$ftp_user_pass='pass';
$connection = 'abc.info';

$errno='';
$connect= fsockopen("abc.info", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

$login = ftp_login($connect, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


if (!$connect) 
{die ("FTP connection has encountered an error!");}


 //exit;


if (!$login)
{die ("But failed at login Attempted to connect to $connection for user $ftp_user_name....");}


?>
```

Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

```
ftp_put($login,"abc.info/$photo",$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],FTP_ASCII) or die("Can not upload");
```

Not sure if my connection is working, but just this line of code

Comment: "but i am only allowed to use fsockopen thru port 80(http) and 443(https)" What does this mean?  FTP uses different ports than this.  If they are not open, you can't use FTP.

Comment: I am very confused by what godaddy said on their forum too, when i test the connect on my localhost, it display no errors at all. But when i put the php onto the server, it doesnt work. I read more, it might be because the php is inside the shared host. So i can't do ftp connect from the inside

Answer (score 0):

[`ftp_login()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php) expects the first parameter to be an resource link identifier (such as that returned by [`ftp_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)). [`fsockopen()`](https://www.php.net/function.fsockopen) returns a file pointer.

You should update your code as follows:

```
$ftp_user_name = 'name';
$ftp_user_pass = 'pass';
$ftp_server = 'abc.info';

$errno='';
$connect = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

if(!ftp_login($connect, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass))
{
    die("But failed at login Attempted to connect to $connection for user $ftp_user_name....");
}
```

Comment: But i can't use ftp_connect tho, godaddy only allows fsockopen(), am i missing something?

Comment: According to GoDaddy, `ftp_connect()` works on their shared hosting: 'With regard to ftp_connect, this is something that will work with our shared hosting'

Comment: Did Godaddy change that? Because on this link (http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/grid-hosting-deluxe-php-curlftp-issue/messages/support/resolve/grid-hosting-deluxe-php-curlftp-issue/) at the bottom, the godaddy support guy said it is not supported on shared hosting. I will give it a try now anyway

Comment: I had a read, and on godaddy they said it might be a problem, if the php is hosted inside the same place, so connecting ftp from within might be a problem, so i am trying from localhost, it connects fine,i am trying to upload a image file but i am having an error Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 69, i edited my question and placed it in there. Wondering if its a connection problem? or is it my code?